# How to remove phone numbers from a contact when they are not visible in edit mode?

Tags: samsung, contacts, android-10, google-contacts

I have a French contact (phone number +33 ...) who went to Japan and got a mobile number there (+81 ...). We discussed via Whats App and Signal and now he is back in France.

**I would like to remove his Japanese phone numbers but I simply cannot.**

This is how I see his contact before the edition:

[image]

As you can see there is one French and two Japanese numbers. I then click on the edit icon and I see:

[image]

**The Japanese numbers are not present.**

There are nowhere to be found, I clicked on "show more fields", but these are just empty extra fields.

I remove the conversations from Signal (it was registered with the Japanese number, this is visible in the screenshot) - nothing. Note that I cannot actually edit a contact in Signal, it just mentions that this (Signal) contact is in my contacts - with the possibility to open the contact and what I get is the first screenshot.

I tried to edit the contact on the phone to add something and somehow influence the Japanese numbers - nothing. I tried a similar edit the contact on a PC via contacts.google.com - nothing. I tried to use the Samsung contact app - same problem.

After using Android extensively for 10+ years, this is the first time I see that. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

OS is Android 10, phone is Samsung Galaxy 9+.

Comment: Have you checked the bottom of the screen? phone numbers and email entries are usually not ordered on data level. If that does not work try to use Google contacts web version in the browser (assuming that your contacts are synced to Google)

Comment: @Robert: yes, I looked everywhere. As I mentioned, on the bottom of the screen there is an entry "extra fields" (the French equivalent in my case), pressing this shows more fields (anniversary, spouse, ...) that are empty. As I also mentioned in the question, I tried with contacts.google.com (tried to remove them but they re not there at all, and then tried to modify the contact by adding a dummy entry to try to "reset" the entry - but no luck)

Comment: Is it possible that you have the contact multiple times and the non-edit view merges them, but when you edit it only one of the merged contacts is displayed? May be you have saved it on SIM card.

Comment: @Robert: no, this is the only entry I see for that user. I will probably just delete it and recreate and I will see how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short on ideas I decided to delete this contact.

Right after it was deleted, **ANOTHER** contact with the same name appeared out of nowhere, holding the two Japanese numbers (and only this, plus the first name, plus the family name).

I then deleted that second (invisible so far) contact and recreated one for my friend (with only the French number).

It worked and I have one single contact.

This is really a mystery to me: I had **one** contact for that user previously, and the other one only appeared when I erased the first one.

I exclusively store contacts in google (not in the SIM or anywhere else) so this is not a traditional "merged contact" view. My wild guess is that Signal must have kept is somehow and presented it in a merged view. That said - it is not possible to edit anything contact-wise in Signal, it always drives you back to the main contact entry (the first screenshot in my question).

I will put it on the shelf with other unsolved mysteries in my 25 years career in IT.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the contact with the bogus number.  Click the 3 dots in the upper right.  Select "add/remove linked contact".   Remove the contact with the bogus number.  Good luck.